# How to use a variable in a custom function in Twilio Studio?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

I would like to use variables from the [`Trigger` widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#trigger-start) in Twilio Studio, for example the `trigger.message.From` variable (that I believe contains the sender's phone number).

Unfortunately, these variables are not passed to the `event` object in my function:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    console.log("received event: " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
};
```

prints:

> received event: {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables need to be passed as parameters in the `run function` configuration. For example, adding a parameter with Key `caller` and Value `{{trigger.message.From}}` should inject this variable in the `event` object:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    console.log("caller is: " + event.caller);
};
```

Try calling the Twilio number and you should see your number:

> caller is: +1XXXXXXXXX